# Broken Python ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd

Tags: bash, python

After installation, I installed python 3.5 by using conda and then removing conda.

Before the removal, I was able to access the pip and etc. On the terminal, any python command results on this as shown on the screenshot below:

```
jjplack@jjplack:~$ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 554, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 536, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 272, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 247, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 237, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 587, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 533, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 417, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_nd import *
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd
```

So, in an attempt to fix, I changed the bash back to python 2 but the error still occurs. Why this is happening and how to fix it?

Here is the bash_config:

```
export PYTHONHOME=/usr/bin
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7
export PATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PATH
```

Comment: Please post the output of `type -a pip python; file $(type -ap pip python)`

Comment: hello @wjandrea

pip is /usr/local/bin/pip
python is /usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/pip: Python script, ASCII text executable
/usr/bin/python:    symbolic link to python2.7

Answer (score 0):

Neverind to fix just type on terminal: `ln -fs /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu/_sysconfigdata.py /usr/lib/python2.7/`